# GStreetviewPanorama parameter values

Tags: google-maps

I am using GStreetviewPanorama for one of my projects to show street view of a location. I want the values of parameters passed in GStreetviewPanorama method so that I can display the location exactly the way maps.google.com does **(same camera orientation)**. I used :

latlngPoint is my GLatLng object here.

```
var panoramaOptions = { latlng: latlngPoint };          
 myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("strpano_div"), panoramaOptions);
```

I also tried

```
  myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("strpano_div"));         
  var myPOV = {yaw:270};
  myPano.setLocationAndPOV(latlngPoint,myPOV);
```

When i passed the address corresponding to above latlng in maps.google.com, the location is shown at a different angle. Please suggest me the best values for GPov options like : yaw,pitch and zoom so that **camera orientation** is exactly same as used by **maps.google.com**.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you comparing it to a search on google that was with a lat,lng or with an address or other search string?

Comment: I am using address to search in google and in my code, for that same address I am using geocoder.getLatLng and panoClient.getNearestPanoramaLatLng with geocoder as GClientGeocoder object and panoClient being GStreetviewClient client.

Answer (score 0):

I have altered this code from the original, but I am sure that you can follow:

```
    var panoPosLat = panoPos.lat() / 180 * Math.PI;
var panoPosLng = panoPos.lng() / 180 * Math.PI;

var y = Math.sin(markerPosLng - panoPosLng) * Math.cos(markerPosLat); 
var x = Math.cos(panoPosLat)*Math.sin(markerPosLat) - Math.sin(panoPosLat)*Math.cos(markerPosLat)*Math.cos(markerPosLng - panoPosLng); 
brng = Math.atan2(y, x) / Math.PI * 195;

var pov = mybigpano2.getPov(); 
pov.heading = parseFloat(brng); 
mybigpano2.setPov(pov);
```

I use 195 degrees because there are many streets that have many curves.

Changing the heading is the key.

I think this is where I found the code:
[enter link description here](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-js-api-v3@googlegroups.com/msg04963.html)

I had some issues with originally and I posted here on stackoverflow:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274766/javascript-length-google-maps)

Hope that helps